# Project Euler #388

Tags: algorithm, visual-studio-2010

I need some help in fine-tuning my algorithm for [Project Euler problem 388](http://projecteuler.net/problem=388). I have concluded that you have to get the `gcd` of the 3 numbers in the co-ordinate and if the `gcd` is 1 than that point gives you a distinct line to the origin. This works fine for up to about 10^5 and then it slows down a lot. Can anyone here help me to see how I can reduce the time? Maybe by eliminating a good chunk of co-ordinates or something? I am using Visual Basic in VS2010.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? It's hard to fine-tune without knowing what. But I suspect you need a better algorithm, and not just fine-tuning.

Comment: Fine tuning won't do, as searching 10^30 lattice points is to much.

Comment: The problem is pretty popular on the internet, see for example the solution here: http://eulersolutions.49.forumer.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=197 - if you understand that you can find more in the Project Euler forum after you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link but I already went through that but couldn't get much help there in terms of speed.

Answer (score 1):

In problem is stated "You are given that D(1 000 000) = 831909254469114121". This could be a hint to search for a recurrence relation.

Comment: How? I don't get it. Can you explain?